# How do we expand on the social plane?

Tags: discussion, chat-sessions

We've set our Google+ and Facebook pages up, but a new problem arises, what do we put there?

How do we handle these pages in a way that will attract people and will make them aware of our existence?

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [the 4th chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/content-managing-for-fb-and-g-4-chat-cast), we've decided to **choose managers for our [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA) and [Google+](https://plus.google.com/111061084179563499110/posts) pages' content**. For that, we have created meta posts where you can nominate yourself for [Facebook](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/facebook-account-manager-nominations) and [Google+](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/google-account-manager-nominations) page content manager.

Also, we have very little people following us on either site, so if you have a Facebook or Google+ profile, **follow/like our page and try to refer your friends to it**.