# Facebook Page Content Manager Nominations

Tags: discussion, status-completed

In our [4th chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/content-managing-for-fb-and-g-4-chat-cast), we have decided to choose a manager for our [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA) content.

This person should have enough free time to maintain our page there, and be well familiarized with the interface of the site. They should also be well-versed in managing a community, and finding and posting about interesting topics to attract users.

### Some notes

- Each nomination should be posted as a separate answer.
- Link the name to your profile (parent and meta) so everyone can see your activity.
- Links to other sites that can also be helpful to the community's understanding of your 'expertise' are also welcome, along with some description you find fitting.

Comment: "He/she should also be well-versed in a lot of anime and manga". How many is a "lot"? I follow about 8, is that good enough? But most of them are of the shounen genre (though I plan to start with seinen pretty soon). That aside, I will tentatively volunteer. I will write a proper answer later.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai: From my point of view, it is enough, as long as you post content of more genres. You may be elected, but still ask other people's opinions/expertise on genres you're not comfortable with (in chat). Consider that other may have seen a ton of anime, but not Naruto (for example), but every once in a while a Naruto question will most likely pop-up, so they'll ask the opinion of people who've seen Naruto on whether or not it is interesting posting material. AFAIC, this position does not exclude participation from the rest of the community, it just determines *who* will post content

Comment: Sorry for the delay in posting the answer. It was neither that I forgot nor that I wasn't interested anymore. It was plain laziness. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I volunteer to be the Facebook page manager. My profiles on the [main site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/99/deidara-senpai) and on [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/99/deidara-senpai). I am an active [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/arvindpai) user and also a regular TVTropes reader and [contributor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/el.php?findfor=apai).

As an Indian working in an American company, I am familiar with both Eastern and Western cultures, though I don't claim to be an expert in either. This may be of some value managing a multi-cultural community.

Comment: Please comment if any more information is needed. :)

Comment: From the chat I noticed some concern about me being in a ... well, non-American timezone, but believe me, it isn't that big a deal. I have been working with American colleagues for over 2 years, and once you get over the initial hurdles, timezone doesn't really matter, and you even feel like you are buddy-buddy with the other guys in the same room (though only for an hour or so). :) Besides, there are a number of Asians in this community.

Comment: There was no concern over you being in a non-American time zone in terms of getting this done (that is essentially a non-issue). We were actually just trying to figure out how to contact you to ask if you were still interested in this. If you're reading the chat backlogs then it's irrelevant anyway.