# What types of content should we post on our community pages to help promote this site?

Tags: discussion, chat-sessions, site-promotion

After having chosen our content managers for our [Google+ page](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/google-page-content-manager-nominations) and [Facebook page](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/facebook-page-content-manager-nominations), we now need to generate some content to post on them.
What do you think can help in the growth of a solid network of followers?

Answer (score 1):

After [some discussion in our sixth Chat Cast](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/sixth-chat-cast-content-for-social-media-promotion) on how to use our [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA) and [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111061084179563499110/posts) community pages, we've reached the following conclusion:

1. We should try to post more interesting non-Q&A content (news, trailers, show and tell, etc.) to help generate discussion and traffic to the site. Make sure to include pictures whenever possible! Feel free to share any interesting news, videos, or tidbits in our ["Social Page Content Discussion" chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7735/social-page-content-discussion)!
2. Post interesting and memorable Q&A from this site on our [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA) and [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111061084179563499110/posts) community pages, and/or tweet them yourselves on Twitter (The [Lelouch](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2438/63) and [Clannad After Story](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/195/63) questions and answers are good examples.)
3. We need a better name for our community site. Please post you suggestions for names, logo, and/or mascot ideas in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/426/63).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how specific you're looking for, but I think that [What differentiates anime from regular cartoons?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons) and [Do people in the anime or manga actually eat Pokemon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/836/do-people-in-the-anime-or-manga-actually-eat-pokemon) should be included because the first is something that interested people should know and the second is something that a lot of people are curious about. They are also the two highest rated questions.

Comment: We already tried the pokemon one on reddit r/pokemon. It didn't get much momentum. As for the anime vs. cartoon one... I don't think that's the kind of question we want to promote too much of.