# Google+ Page Content Manager Nominations

Tags: discussion, status-completed

In our [4th chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/content-managing-for-fb-and-g-4-chat-cast), we have decided to choose a manager for our [Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/111061084179563499110/posts) content.

This person should have enough free time to maintain our page there, and be well familiarized with the interface of the site. They should also be well-versed in managing a community, and finding and posting about interesting topics to attract users.

### Some notes

- Each nomination should be posted as a separate answer.
- Link the name to your profile (parent and meta) so everyone can see your activity.
- Links to other sites that can also be helpful to the community's understanding of your 'expertise' are also welcome, along with some description you find fitting.

Comment: Why not make this a community instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[Anime.SE profile](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/274/eric)**
- **[Meta profile](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/274/eric)**
- **[G+ profile](http://gplus.to/ekumlin)**

My own G+ feed has little activity, due mostly to not liking to self-indulge on content; my activity is mostly in commenting and visiting communities ([Anime](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107398296600629207634) included). I'll have no problem posting new content to the page's feed, though.

In terms of managing communities, I've had a presence on more than one Wiki, as well as programming-related forums for quite a while, and one in a gaming community. (Links to these omitted as the communities' members have moved on to new things and the forums shut down.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time at the moment but I can take care of the page, if no one decides to take the mantle.